# Golang, mongodb: getting database error details/codes

Tags: go, mgo

I'd like to return an appropriate HTTP status code depending on the returned DB error.
For instance, if a record not found, I'd send 404, if it is something else - 500, and so on ...

At the moment, I just get the standard `error` type from mgo.
How can I get an int error code so that I can analyse it and return appropriate HTTP code?

Example:

```
func (db *DB) GetRecord() (*Person, error) {
    c := db.C("people")
    res := Person{}
    err := c.Find(bson.M{"name": "Alexandra"}).One(&res)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &res, nil
}
```

So this function just gets a record and returns an error (in case of a failure) which is threaded to HTTP handler.

```
func (s *State) Index(c *gin.Context) {
    res, err := s.DB.GetArticles()
    if err != nil {
        d := gin.H{
            "error": gin.H{
                "status": "404",
                "title":  "Get record error!",
                "detail": err.Error(),
            },
        }
        c.JSON(404, d)
    }
    content := gin.H{
        "data": gin.H{
            "type": "records",
            "id":   res.Id,
            "attributes": gin.H{
                "Phone": res.Phone,
            },
        },
    }
    c.JSON(200, content)
}
```

The JSON error reply has a detail field for the actual DB error and status field for the HTTP status code. HTTP status code has to be determined based on the DB error.

So how do I get a detailed error with an int error code so I can `switch` through it and return a proper HTTP status?

I can see the `QueryError` and `LastError` in the documentation but I cannot figure out how to return them. I suppose this question boils down to the correct way of using `QueryError` and `LastError` types.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do a type switch of the error. In each case statement, the error will be of whatever type so you can then access whatever fields it might have, like error messages.

```
func (s *State) Index(c *gin.Context) {
    res, err := s.DB.GetArticles()
    if err != nil {
        switch err.(type){
        case ErrNotFound:
            d := gin.H{
                "error": gin.H{
                    "status": "404",
                    "title":  "Get record error!",
                    "detail": err.Error(),
                },
            }
            c.JSON(404, d)
       case *QueryError:
            //how you want to deal with a queryError
       case *LastError:
            //how you want to deal with a LastError

       }
    }
    content := gin.H{
        "data": gin.H{
            "type": "records",
            "id":   res.Id,
            "attributes": gin.H{
                "Phone": res.Phone,
            },
        },
    }
c.JSON(200, content)
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it does not compile. It errors out with: "impossible type switch case: err (type error) cannot have dynamic type mgo.QueryError (missing Error method)" Any thoughts? I cannot believe it is so difficult to get those error codes form DB

Comment: It looks like QueryError needed to be *QueryError and LastError needed to be *LastError. I have updated the code

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I figured that out.. It works now but I still can not get those DB error codes. Any error simulation I do, it just returns a string error like "not found". It never returns `LastError` or `QuerryError`. Those two structs have the Code field, which I need,  and I can not get to them.